# 'Automated' option not shown in 'Automation Status' dropdown in Testcase work Item in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-server-2019, devops-services

In  Azure DevOps documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/build-test-integration?view=azure-devops

It mentions that :

Field nameDescriptionWork item typeAutomation Status1The status of a test case. You can specify the following values:
Automated
Not Automated
Planned
I am unable to see the Automated Option in the dropdown there are only 2 options available in the dropdown - 'Not Automated' and Planned. Can you please let me know when do you intend to fix this problem ?

Comment: i dont get you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Automated` value for `Automation Status` field is auto set when the test case work item is associated to a test case method. It seems your Test case work item is not associated to test case.

[image]

If the Test case work item is not associated. You will only get 'Not Automated' and 'Planned' options in the `Automation Status` field.

[image]

Check document [Associate automated tests with test cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=azure-devops) to associate your test cases.

When the Test case work item is associated to a test case. You can see the associated test case in the **Associated Automation** tab. See below:

[image]